# install4j deploy no jar file

Tags: install4j

I'm new to install4j.
So I hope this question is easy to answer and not obvios.

I involved to an Java-development-project.
We decided to use install4j to create a nice installer for our customers.

Now i've got an install4j license and testing to create an installer.
I Use the install4j Launcher Wizard to make a .exe file out of my .jar file.

Now the Problem: If I remove the .jar file from the installer, the .exe file doesn't work anymore.

So the question: Is it possible to deploy with install4j an .exe file without the .jar file ?

WebStart is not an option in this project.

Answer (score 2):

The .exe is just a launcher to start the JVM. Your Java code is not compiled into native code by install4j. If you want to protect your code, you have to use an obfuscator, for example [yguard](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think install4j can package the Jar inside the executable, as shown in this blog post:

http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2010/12/my-first-try-with-install4j-tutorial.html